# navigator.share not working in mobile browser(chrome v64)

Tags: javascript, android-intent, mobile-chrome

I have been trying to trigger the Intent Share in the Android browser from javascript using the `navigator.share`.

Following is an example code:

```
$("#printTest").click(function(e){
    if (navigator.share === undefined){
        alert('Undefined!');
    }
    else{
        alert('Sharing!');
        navigator.share({title: 'Example Page', text: 'https://example.com'});
    }
});
```

When I try to click on the button from chrome in ubuntu, it opens a window for sharing(which shows no apps to select though). But the same is not working on any android mobile browser. I have tested in Chrome for Android version 64 and Chrome for Android Dev also. All of the shows the alert 'Undefined' even after enabling the flag `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`navigator.share` will only work on websites with `https` and not `HTTP`

Comment: damn and lets encrypt only give certificate for dns names and no ip... basically you have to pay a domain to test this function.

Comment: Sharing will work if you are on http://localhost. If you developing on mobile, you can use port forwarding to use localhost domain on phone even if your local server is on PC.

Comment: @NicolasManzini  for local testing over HTTPS you could use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: @NicolasManzini I would never recommend ngrok to a casual developer or for use in a company without checking with cyber security guys first. It is a MASSIVE security risk to do this and is a well known entry point for malicious hackers.